# Kindle books on another iCloud account

Tags: icloud

If I add another iCloud account to my iPhone, will I be able to access my kindle books on that iCloud account?

Answer (score 1):

The login information is discrete for Amazon Kindle and Apple iCloud. You may need to re-login to your Kindle account, but the iCloud account shouldn't effect it any other way.